# Vim команды 'w' (word) и 'e' (end word)

Tags: vim

Команды w не переносит меня в начало следующего слова в кириллическом тексте например: записывает - ЗаПИСыВаеТ (в верхнем регистре "прыжки")

Аналогично с командой 'e'.

система windows 10, vim 8.1 (2018 May 18)

config

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set number
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
set iminsert=0
set imsearch=0
highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Cyan

set hlsearch
set incsearch

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', {'on':'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
call plug#end()

"mappings

map <C-n> : NERDTreeToggle<CR>

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
```

Comment: запустите для проверки без конфигурации (опция `-u NONE`)

Comment: да, в таком режиме правильно работает w, b и e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо используйте:

`set encoding=utf-8`

**в начале** конфиг-файла, либо:

`set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`

---

### Меню и юникод

Для того чтобы меню отображалось правильно в utf-8 `set encoding=utf-8` необходимо размещать **в самом начале** конфига, т.е. это первые настройки которые должен читать VIM. Для более полноценной работы в utf-8 на русском языке можно использовать следующие настройки (опять же, в начале файла конфигурации):

```
    " Отображение кириллицы во внутренних сообщениях программы
    let $LANG='ru_RU.UTF-8'
    lan mes ru_RU.UTF-8
    " Отображение кириллицы в меню
    set langmenu=ru_RU.UTF-8
    set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! set encoding=utf-8 делает меню gvim  крякозяблики, а iskeyword - работает!

Comment: Добавил пояснения для работы с юникодом в интерфейсе.

Comment: Спасибо, разместил первой строкой set encoding=utf-8 (Успел прочитать удаленный комментарий)